# Non-blocking call for reading descriptor

Tags: c, unix

I have a fd descriptor, which I can use to read from by calling `read(fd, buffer,...)`. Now, I want to check if there is anything to read before actually making the call, because the call is blocking. How do I do this?

Comment: The behavior of read with respect to blocking varies depending on the descriptor type.  To what type of device does `fd` refer?

Comment: standard inputs, right now, it's blocking

Comment: @KenRockot so if I have a regular file it is different than for example fd which is a socketDescriptor ?

Answer (score 79, accepted):

```
int flags = fcntl(fd, F_GETFL, 0);
fcntl(fd, F_SETFL, flags | O_NONBLOCK);
```

The code snippet above will configure such a descriptor for non-blocking access. If data is not available when you call read, then the system call will fail with a return value of -1 and errno is set to EAGAIN. See the [fcntl](http://linux.die.net/man/2/fcntl) man pages for more information.

Alternatively, you can use [select](http://www.lowtek.com/sockets/select.html) with a configurable timeout to check and/or wait a specified time interval for more data. This method is probably what you want and can be much more efficient.

Comment: And then check for -1 returns from `read` and that `errno` is `EAGAIN`.

Comment: good doc about file with non-blocking support setting errno at [opengroup](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/read.html)

Comment: This is NOT the correct answer. O_NONBLOCK against a regular fs has no effect (read() will keep blocking) and select() will always erroneously report the fd as "ready".
Reliable non-blocking IO for regular files on Linux is basically (and unfortunately) not supported.

Comment: [Some](http://www.linux-mag.com/id/308/) [good](https://www.remlab.net/op/nonblock.shtml) [sources](http://neugierig.org/software/blog/2011/12/nonblocking-disk-io.html) on regular files and non-blocking I/O. However, if `fd` is stdin, then it seems harmless to let `O_NONBLOCK` speed things up when reading from a terminal/pipe and do nothing when reading from a file.

Answer (score 18):

Use `select` or `poll` to query whether the file descriptor has data available for read:

```
fd_set fds;
FD_ZERO(&fds);
FD_SET(&fds, fd);
if (select(fd+1, &fds, 0, 0)==1) /* there is data available */
```

Comment: Isn't is `FD_SET(fd, &fds);` instead ?

Comment: Probably, but `select` is a horrible idea anyway because `FD_SET` invokes UB if `fd>=FD_SETSIZE`. Just use `poll`.

Comment: `poll()` is now standardized in POSIX so it can always be used in place of `select()`. http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/poll.html

Comment: Yes, `poll` should be used instead.

Comment: IIRC poll on macOS AND serial port does not work. I could not locate the reference now but I have distinct recollection that this is or was the case. So as this was  old question was not Linux specific I think the recommendation to use poll() might be bad.

Comment: How would I then know *how much* data is available for read? Since I have to specify a buffer size to read, I can't simply read "all" of it.

Comment: @jhasse: That sounds like a separate question (ask it) not a comment on this old answer to a different question.

Answer (score 3):

Depending on what you're doing you might be able to turn the problem inside out and use [`select`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/select) to tell you when your file descriptor has something to read.

Answer (score 2):

use poll for timeout:

```
struct pollfd p;
int n;
while ((n = poll(&p, 1, iTo)) < 0) 
{
    if (errno == EAGAIN || errno == EINTR)
       continue;
}

if (!n) {
    errno = ETIMEDOUT;
}

while ((len = read(Fd, anyBuff, sizeof(anyenter code hereBuff))) < 0) {
    if (errno == EAGAIN || errno == EINTR)
        continue;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use `select` or `poll` functions to check if there are something to read from the descriptor.

Comment: Can you add some more details? An example would be nice.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the API or system/tool you are using for your specific programming purpose. (descriptors/file descriptors have many uses in Linux programming such as socket programming, file manipulation, shared_memory, etc.)

For example one time I used inotify (for monitoring file system events). This API gives you ability to create non-blocking file from the first point and there's no need to use fcntl or such APIs to modify the created file descriptor.

Probably other tools or API's that you're going to use have such functionality and you can set such option in their initiation or such steps (check this first).

But generally yes using fcntl is the answer and it might be interesting to know that inotify itself uses fcntl itself too. (refer to the manual pages of Linux)

select() can give you a same functionality as it operates on file descriptors for monitoring events with a specified limited time but keep in mind that the main usage of select is for monitoring **multiple** file descriptors.