# How to make a timer that counts down from 30 by 1 every second?

Tags: c++, windows, c++-chrono

I want to make a timer that displays 30, 29 etc going down every second and then when there is an input it stops. I know you can do this:

```
    for (int i = 60; i > 0; i--)
    {
        cout << i << endl;
        Sleep(1000);
    }
```

This will output 60, 59 etc. But this doesn't allow for any input while the program is running. How do I make it so you can input things while the countdown is running?

**Context**

This is not a homework assignment. I am making a text adventure game and there is a section where an enemy rushes at you and you have 30 seconds to decide what you are going to do. I don't know how to make the timer able to allow the user to input things while it is running.

Comment: Sounds like a good homework assignment.  What have you tried?  What problems have you run into?  What questions do you have about your implementation?  How can we help you short of doing your homework for you?

Comment: This isn't homework, sorry for the bad question, I cleared it up tell me if you need more information.

Comment: Fwiw, I don't downvote without warning.  These downvotes aren't mine.  I recommend a thread to do the countdown and display, and that thread should also check a flag for "input".  I also recommend `std::this_thread::sleep_until`, over `Sleep` to keep your count down accurate, and to make the logic simpler.

Comment: There's no way around this without doing some asynchronous/multithreaded programming, unfortunately, since both of `Sleep` and `cin` will stall your program. Take a look at this answer which uses `std::future` with a timeout to read user input: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47774984/5023438

Comment: I don't totally understand that, I put it into my code but doesn't it just do the same thing as ```string input getline(cin, input) cout << input; ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your game is about 1 frame per second, so user input is a problem. Normally games have higher frame rate like this:

```cpp
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    // Initialization
    ULARGE_INTEGER initialTime;
    ULARGE_INTEGER currentTime;
    FILETIME ft;
    GetSystemTimeAsFileTime(&ft);
    initialTime.LowPart = ft.dwLowDateTime;
    initialTime.HighPart = ft.dwHighDateTime;
    LONGLONG countdownStartTime = 300000000; // 100 Nano seconds
    LONGLONG displayedNumber = 31; // Prevent 31 to be displayed

    // Game loop
    while (true) {
        GetSystemTimeAsFileTime(&ft); // 100 nano seconds
        currentTime.LowPart = ft.dwLowDateTime;
        currentTime.HighPart = ft.dwHighDateTime;

        //// Read Input ////
        bool stop = false;
        SHORT key = GetKeyState('S');
        if (key & 0x8000)
            stop = true;

        //// Game Logic ////
        LONGLONG elapsedTime = currentTime.QuadPart - initialTime.QuadPart;
        LONGLONG currentNumber_100ns = countdownStartTime - elapsedTime;
        if (currentNumber_100ns <= 0) {
            std::cout << "Boom!" << std::endl;
            break;
        }
        if (stop) {
            std::wcout << "Stopped" << std::endl;
            break;
        }

        //// Render ////
        LONGLONG currentNumber_s = currentNumber_100ns / 10000000 + 1;
        if (currentNumber_s != displayedNumber) {
            std::cout << currentNumber_s << std::endl;
            displayedNumber = currentNumber_s;
        }
    }

    system("pause");
}
```

Comment: I don't exactly understand what you're saying here

Comment: To make it simple: Include `conio.h`. Insert `if (_getch()=='s')break;` before `Sleep(1000)` so that the loop can stop early when you press s key.

Comment: Now it only runs when I type a character

Comment: @evilhoomans42: Answer suggests to use [non-blocking-call-for-reading-descriptor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5616092/non-blocking-call-for-reading-descriptor), so you avoid thread with that solution.

Comment: @evilhoomans42 Sorry that is a bad idea. I'll rewrite my answer.

Comment: Is there a way to make it take string inputs so like multiple character inputs?

Comment: @evilhoomans42 Of course. You have to respond to and store all keys you need in "Read Input" section, process all input chars in "Game Logic" secion, and show  those chars in "Render" section if you want. All games have this kind of structure, and you can virtually do anything.

Comment: What does the `0x8000` in the if statement in the read input section do?

Comment: Also how would I do what you said

Comment: `0x8000` is to get the highest bit of `key`. Check `GetKeyState()`'s document [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getkeystate).

Comment: Just want full code? Implementing a text input area in games, you need quite some work. I suggest you just make a single-key version.

Answer (score 0):

If you're running this on Linux, you can use the classic select() call.  When used in a while-loop, you can wait for input on one or more file descriptors, while also providing a timeout after which the select() call must return.  Wrap it all in a loop and you'll have both your countdown and your handling of standard input.

https://linux.die.net/man/2/select

Comment: unfortunately I am using windows

Comment: winsock2 has select

Comment: what is winstock2?

Comment: Originally put out by trumpet it provided a TCP stack for Windows 3.0 so you could connect to your dial-up service provider....